# Setting wifi ssid with a space in it

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi, android-things

I am trying to setup the wifi on my android things raspberry pi following [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#connecting_wi-fi).

My Ssid contains a space in the name let's say "my ssid".

I tried to put quotes around it like this:

```
$ adb shell am startservice \
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect \
    -e ssid "my ssid" \
    -e passphrase secretpassword
```

When looking at the logcat for the wifi connection I see:

```
WifiNetworkHistory: saving network history: "my"NONE gw: null Network Selection-status: NETWORK_SELECTION_ENABLED ephemeral=false choice:null link:0 status:2 nid:0 hasEverConnected: false
WifiConfigurator: Wifi failed to connect in 30000 ms
```

How can I set my wifi correctly?

Comment: Did you try `-e ssid "my\ ssid" ` ? Basically escaping the space character itself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To enter characters like "(double quotes),*(asterisk), (space), we need to use **escape sequences**( i.e a backslash before the character) to tell the compiler to read the character as a part of the string instead of a command (for example double quotes is usually interpreted as the start/end of a string, to interpret it as a character in the string we use \").

**The solution**

```
$ adb shell am startservice \
-n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
-a WifiSetupService.Connect \
-e ssid "my\ ssid" \
-e passphrase secretpassword
```

Comment: were you able to connect with wifi or ethernet cable is required all the time?

Comment: You need an ethernet cable to setup the wifi. Once your wifi is setup, you don't need the ethernet anymore.